# Image as pushpin on maps - Windows phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, here-api

im trying to add a image to a windows phone 8 map, to serve as a pushpin

i have the following code on my XAML

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:maps="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Maps.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Maps"
x:Class="Cartuxa.Contactos"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
mc:Ignorable="d"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Assets/Images/bkContacts@2x.png"/>
    </Grid.Background>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28"/>

    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.RowSpan="2" Margin="0,-6,0,6">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="127*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="329*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Image HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="18.75,57.5,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Source="/Assets/Images/logo@2x.png" Stretch="Fill" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Width="221" Height="72"/>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="30,152,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Contactos" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FFCD3333" FontFamily="Helvetica" FontSize="36" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Width="174"/>
        <Button HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,201,-13,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="255" Background="White" Height="66" BorderThickness="0" Grid.Column="1" BorderBrush="#FFFF0909">
            <Grid Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                <Image Name="POI_Left" Source="/Assets/Images/POI_Gray@2x.png" RenderTransformOrigin="0.4,0.274" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="-180,0,0,0" Stretch="None"/>

                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left"
               Margin="13,6,-22,0"
               TextWrapping="Wrap"
               Text="Paços dos Condes de Basto"
               VerticalAlignment="Top"
               FontFamily="Helvetica"
               Foreground="Black"
               FontSize="14" Width="182"/>
            </Grid>
        </Button>
        <maps:Map Name="contactosMaps" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,271,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="-1.737,-0.175" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Height="290" Width="480"/>
        <Button  Name="Contactos_Btn1"
                 Click="Contactos_Btn1_Click"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                 Margin="-17,201,242,0"
                 VerticalAlignment="Top"
                 Width="255"
                 Background="White"
                 Height="65"
                 BorderThickness="0"
                 Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <Grid Name="pushRed" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                <Image x:Name="POI_Right" Source="/Assets/Images/POI_Red@2x.png" RenderTransformOrigin="0.4,0.274" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="-190,0,0,0" Stretch="None"/>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="14,6,-14,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Fundação Eugénio De Almeida" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontFamily="Helvetica" Foreground="Black" FontSize="14"/>
            </Grid>
        </Button>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="26,606,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Width="406" Height="22">
            <Run FontFamily="Helvetica" Text="Fundação Eugénio de Almeida"/>
            <LineBreak/>
            <Run/>
        </TextBlock>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="30,655,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Width="402" Height="85" FontFamily="Helvetica">
            <Run Text="Páteo de São Miguel "/>
            <LineBreak/>
            <Run Text="Apartado 2001, 7001-901 Évora "/>
            <LineBreak/>
            <Run Text="Portugal"/>
            <LineBreak/>
            <Run/>
        </TextBlock>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="30,745,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Width="406" Height="22" Text="Tel. (+351) 266 748 300 "/>
        <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="30,773,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Width="406" Height="22">
            <Run FontFamily="Helvetica" Text="Fax. (+ 351) 266 705 149"/>
            <Run FontFamily="Helvetica"/>
            <Run/>
        </TextBlock>

    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

and my .cs code is the following

```
public partial class Contactos : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    public Contactos()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded +=Contactos_Loaded;

    }

    private void Contactos_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateMap();
    }

    private void UpdateMap()
    {

        MapOverlay pin = new MapOverlay();
        pin.Content = pushRed;
        pin.GeoCoordinate = new GeoCoordinate(38.57325D, -7.90546);
        pin.PositionOrigin = new Point(0, 0.5);

        MapLayer pinLayer = new MapLayer();
        pinLayer.Add(pin);
        contactosMaps.Layers.Add(pinLayer);
        contactosMaps.SetView(new GeoCoordinate(38.57325D, -7.90546), 14D);
    }

    private void Contactos_Btn1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

when i try to run my project, it loads the map but a few moments later i get this exception

"Additional information: Value does not fall within the expected range."

when i do the "contactosMaps.Layers.Add(pinLayer);"

can't i have that Grid with the image as a pushpin?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the Phone.Controls.Toolkit as described here:-

http://wp.qmatteoq.com/maps-in-windows-phone-8-and-phone-toolkit-a-winning-team-part-1/

The toolkit can be found at either of

http://phone.codeplex.com/

or

https://www.nuget.org/packages/WPtoolkit

You can then either add the image directly in your XAML as follows:-

```
<maps:Map Loaded="MapControl_Loaded" ZoomLevel="18" Name="MapControl">
   <toolkit:MapExtensions.Children>
       <toolkit:Pushpin x:Name="MyPushpin">
           <toolkit:Pushpin.Template>
               <ControlTemplate TargetType="toolkit:Pushpin">
                   <StackPanel>
                       <Image Source="/Images/MapScreen/MapScreenCurrentLocationPin.png" Stretch="Uniform" Width="50" Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </toolkit:Pushpin.Template>
        </toolkit:Pushpin>
    </toolkit:MapExtensions.Children>
</maps:Map>
```

or you can add it in C# as follows:-

```
MapOverlay overlay = new MapOverlay
{
    GeoCoordinate = myMap.Center,
    Content = new Ellipse
    {
        Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red),
        Width = 40,
        Height = 40
     }
};
MapLayer layer = new MapLayer();
layer.Add(overlay);

myMap.Layers.Add(layer);
```

You should be able to add a Grid with an image instead of an ellipse as shown above.

Let me know if this worked for you.

Comment: Hi what about the tooltip for that image, i tried and succeeded in adding image as pushpin in map,but I couldn't add tooltip to the image, anybody help me to do this?

Comment: For this, on your pushpin tap, you need to create a new map overlay and add it to your map with the overlay geocoordinate the same as your pushpin geocoordinate. To close the tooltip, override the map tap event and if the tooltip overlay has been added(check the number of layers in your map), remove it from the map. Also if your map has multiple pushpins, switch the overlay from one pushpin to another on pushpin tap by changing the content and geocoordinate.