# How can display an image of a MapIcon?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I Created a MapIcon, and with the Image property I inserted an image from the project, but I can not see the image, and even the name of the placeholder.
Where am I wrong?

```
MapLocationFinderResult result = await MapLocationFinder.FindLocationsAsync(muss.Indirizzo,null);
Geopoint posizione1 = result.Locations.FirstOrDefault().Point;
MapIcon arrivo = new MapIcon();
arrivo.Image = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Flag.png"));
arrivo.Location = posizione1;
arrivo.Title = muss.NomeMuseo;

MyMap.MapElements.Add(arrivo);
```

Comment: Are you sure about the name of the image, and the location? Make sure you have the image within the assets folder.

Comment: I double checked and the name of the image is right. The image is located inside the Assets folder and is included in the project

Comment: Map control and get current location using #UWP CSharp https://youtu.be/xJveKt99MXY With Custom pin image

Answer (score 0):

According to the `MapIcon` [class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.maps.mapicon.aspx) it only supports for `WP8.1 Runtime` apps. If you're in a WP8 application then why don't you create a custom `Pushpin` for your map.

[Custom Pushpins](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/windows-phone-drawing-custom-pushpins-on-the-map-control-what-options-do-we-have), within this post find the third option which talks about having an image as the `Pushpin`.

- [Image as pushpin on maps - Windows phone 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21295870/)
- [MSDN Sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Windows-Phone-8-Maps-API-95ef7816)

Comment: I'm creating a Windows Phone 8.1 app. The class MapIcon me it works, but it does not work the Image property. I can not view the image

Comment: @SMM Your code seems to be okay, maybe the image's opacity is high, try reducing it. Insert another image and see.